# Position fixed does not work with transform CSS property

Tags: css, css-transforms

Is there a way to keep the "Hello" element fixed? So that when a user scrolls up or down the hello element does not move from its position.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/VR5P8/

Here is the CSS:

```
#hello {
position: fixed;
border: 1px solid #000;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: white;
}
```

Here is the code of the wrapper of the "Hello" element:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(394px, 0px);
```

Comment: You've applied the transform to the wrong div: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/VR5P8/1/